# Using Pytest, I can't find a way to run 2 test classes at once in parallel, while each class has several tests?

Tags: python, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

I'm using Pytest, and having the following structure of tests :

ClassA.py

> 

---------------test_a

---------------test_b

---------------test_c

**And Also**

ClassB.py

> 

---------------test_d

---------------test_e

---------------test_f

I'm running my tests via terminal command
(i.e.: pytest -v -s  ClassA.py)

My question:
Is there a way to run ClassA & ClassB in parallel (2 instances you might say),
while maintaining order on each class - separately?
Meaning I want all tests from ClassA will run on 1st browser instance, and all tests from ClassB will run on a different instance.

I'm also familiar with parallel test execution using the 'pytest-xdist' plug-in.
But once using it the test cases that are in ClassA and ClassB are executed in the mixed order, so that is not good for me.

**EDITED:**
My main purpose is to avoid from test_a running on a separate browser instance of test_b.
I would like the tests on each class to run on the same browser instance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Mark the test with order using pytest-order plugin and use pytest n 2 --dist loadfile. It will run Class A test in one browser and then initiate ClassB test in 2nd browser. Make sure you are passing the driver instance from conftest with  the scope set to class

Comment: I don't think he would need pytest-order plugin. Defining the browser in classA and classB and using `--dist loadfile` should be enough in this case.